# Difference between initComponent and onRender in EXT JS form panel

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

How do this two different methods differ in functionality? What can it put initcomponent and what kind of things would be put in onRender?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

initComponent is called early on when a component is being built, onRender happens when the component is being rendered. You generally do the majority of your component's construction on the initComponent class, ie if you are extending a grid you can build your column model, store, plugins, etc in the initComponent method. The onRender could be useful if you want to do anything special at render time, this is less commonly used than the initComponent though.

This is a good example to follow for building your components: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/writer/UserForm.js

Comment: Good answer. Is it possible to make an Ajax call in `initComponent` to get some data and populate the UI with it? it seems to mess up my code.

Comment: Yes, you can make an Ajax request within any function. The problem you are running into is probably because the callback method is trying to manipulate properties on the component that may not be rendered yet, hence you may be having errors.

Comment: yeah I'm exactly having that issue. How do I overcome that?

Comment: Sorry for not answering back earlier. You can have a your ajax success callback method make modifications to that component after the fact. Or there is a library called ext-basex which adds functionality to ajax requests by giving you the ability to specify that your ajax request is synchronous, just add 'async: false' to your ajax request config.

Answer (score 2):

This might help: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_2_Overview#Component_Life_Cycle